# Django FileWrapper object: How to hook in clean-up action

Tags: django

Suppose the django.core.servers.basehttp.FileWrapper class is used to serve back content from a temporary file.

When the client completes the file download, the temporary file needs to be deleted.

How can one hook into the FileWrapper object, to perform such a clean-up action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run on unix system then unlink temp file right after opening. Disk space will be freed after closing file handle by FileWrapper at the end of downloading.

Comment: That's brilliant. The FileWrapper class' initializer takes an open file object. So issuing the unlink system call is a solution. Thanks!